# How to reduce redundant spaces between keywords in C++ code using astyle

Tags: c++, astyle

I always type more spaces between keywords, or between identifiers without awareness. How can I configure astyle configuration file to reduce them to only one space automatically?
For example:

```
int       main(int argc, const    char *argv[]) {
    int x    = 4;
    return 0;
}
```

Would become:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int x = 4;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can (I've had similar issues with various 3rd-party libraries lately). +1 anyway because I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Just clean the stickiness from underneath your spacebar key. No 3rd-party libraries required.

Comment: @CodyGray That's not particularly helpful when the code in question is coming from someone else, and manually cleaning up space-spam is time-consuming and somewhat annoying imho.

Comment: @CodyGray although I clean my keyboard, this problem still exists

Comment: You might want to think about eliminating multiple spaces via `sed`, and then have `astyle` adding the indenting spaces again as a two-step process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) in-place of astyle.

Comment: I'm a Vim guy myself so it's untested but [this](https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode) plugin appears to do integrate it.